# Model not printable // Solidify doesn't work properly

Tags: 3d-printing, solidify-modifier

I made my first 3d model which I'd like to print, but I am experiencing issues with the solidifying part.
My model looks like this: [image]
When I import it to FlashPrint (The slicer I use), it looks like this: [image] As you can see, something is wrong with some parts of the model and it appears glitchy. It doesn't give me a warning when I import the model.
It still looks fine, but as soon as I slice it, the glitchy parts are completely ignored and removed. This looks like this: [image]
If anyone could help me to make my model printable, that would be great. I am not entirely sure how to include the .blend file to this post, but let's hope it worked and it's attached somewhere.[image]
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your mesh looks like this ...

- *Face Orientation* mismatch
- not a single mesh (three parts)
- overlapping faces

[image]

The easiest would be to start from scratch:

- Add torus, sphere (like 64 sides), delete half
- Select loops on torus and sphere with (Alt+Shift+click), search for *Bridge Edge Loop*. Like this also middle part will be red (continues inner side).

[image]

- Add *Solidify* > *Even Thickness.* Top edge jumps up, apply modifier and fix it manually (by adding one edge loop and reposition.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! May I ask how you split the three parts like this? Did you select all the vertices of the individual parts and move/split them or is there some kind if shortcut for that?

Comment: Select vertex and press Ctrl+L (Select Linked) ... :)

Comment: I have also Q :) how did you twist partly the topology of sphere and bottom part?

Comment: Simple and honest answer: I don't know either :')

It's my first time working with Blender, and I am having quite some trouble with it…

Comment: OK so few tips ... see edit.